# Прописная буква

Tags: прописная-строчная

Всегда считала, что Донецкая Народная Республика все три слова пишутся с прописной буквы, вчера по телевизору в нижней строке увидела: Донецкая народная республика. Почему только первое слово пишется с прописной? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как отвечала на подобный вопрос **Грамота.ру**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему я должен **См.** Линк не работает!

Comment: http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%C4%EE%ED%E5%F6%EA%E0%FF+%ED%E0%F0%EE%E4%ED%E0%FF+%F0%E5%F1%EF%F3%E1%EB%E8%EA%E0

Comment: А вообще-то да, slava1947, не надо отвечать голой ссылкой, здесь не принято.